# Method to invert a mapping along a given range

Tags: ruby, algorithm

Say I have this collection of objects:

```
[
 {value: 1, contents: "one"},
 {value: 2, contents: "two"},
 {value: 3, contents: "three"},
 {value: 4, contents: "four"},
 {value: 5, contents: "five"}
]
```

And want to invert the relation of values to contents, like so:

```
[
 {value: 5, contents: "one"},
 {value: 4, contents: "two"},
 {value: 3, contents: "three"},
 {value: 2, contents: "four"},
 {value: 1, contents: "five"}
]
```

I was unable to think of an algorithm to accomplish this. I'm using Ruby, but I'm not so concerned about the code as I am about the method of accomplishing this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We don't write code for you, but we're very happy to help correct the code you've written. Please show us your attempts, and explain why they don't meet your needs. As a hint, I'd suggest that an array of single-element hashes is not a good starting point. Consider a single hash, which will work since you have unique keys. Then look at `keys`, `values`, `reverse` and `zip`. And somewhere in there you might want `map` and `to_h`.

Comment: The fact that you were able to type an example shows that you know at least one method to accomplish this—and I'll bet it's a pretty good method. Take out a pencil and paper and write down your inputs, then write down the mental steps you take to solve the problem. Then turn those steps into code.

Answer (score 3):

```
a = [
  {value: 1, contents: "one"},
  {value: 2, contents: "two"},
  {value: 3, contents: "three"},
  {value: 4, contents: "four"},
  {value: 5, contents: "five"}
]

a.map{|h| h[:value]}.reverse.zip(a.map{|h| h[:contents]})
.map{|k, v| {value: k, contents: v}}
# => 
# [
#  {:value=>5, :contents=>"one"},
#  {:value=>4, :contents=>"two"},
#  {:value=>3, :contents=>"three"},
#  {:value=>2, :contents=>"four"},
#  {:value=>1, :contents=>"five"}
#]
```

Or,

```
a.each_index.map{|i| {value: a[-i - 1][:value], contents: a[i][:contents]}}
```

Comment: I count three `map`s, a `reverse` and a `zip`. There's no reason you should iterate over the data more than once to solve this problem, much less *five* times.

Comment: Up Vote for the second solution as I agree with @Jordan the iteration need only occur 1 time as it does in the `each_index` solution. That being said I also agree with @theTinMan's comment on the post that a single Hash would be a better solution for the concept as a whole.

Comment: Not many people know about `zip` but this is exactly what it does best.

Comment: @tadman I was going to say that `zip` is a poor fit here, as evidenced by the `map` and `reverse` contortions required by @sawa's first attempt, but then I realized you're right. Since you didn't post your own answer, I edited mine to include a method with `zip` that requires iterating over the data only once (when you use `lazy`). Great intuition!

Answer (score 1):

Letting `arr` equal your array of hashes, here are a couple of ways you could do it.

**Two passes, no indices**

```
value_vals = arr.map {|h| h[:value]}.reverse
  #=> [5, 4, 3, 2, 1] 
arr.map { |h| {value: value_vals.shift, contents: h[:contents]}}
  #=> [{:value=>5, :contents=>"one"},
  #    {:value=>4, :contents=>"two"},
  #    {:value=>3, :contents=>"three"},
  #    {:value=>2, :contents=>"four"},
  #    {:value=>1, :contents=>"five"}]
```

**One pass, but not pretty**

```
arr.each_index.map {|i,a| {value: arr[-1-i][:value], contents: arr[i][:contents]}}
  #=> [{:value=>5, :contents=>"one"},
  #    {:value=>4, :contents=>"two"},
  #    {:value=>3, :contents=>"three"},
  #    {:value=>2, :contents=>"four"},
  #    {:value=>1, :contents=>"five"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

#### TL;DR

```
arr.zip(arr.reverse).map {|a, b| a.merge(value: b[:value]) }
```

Since `reverse` makes a copy of the array, this will take twice as much memory as other methods—which for most data sets probably isn't an issue at all. But if it is, there's an easy way to avoid it. See the "Bonus" section at the end of my answer.

#### Building an algorithm

The simplest (and probably best) solution is to walk the array, and for each item get the `:value` from its counterpart at the other end of the array. You can get an item's "counterpart" by subtracting the item's index from the index of the last item (i.e. the size of the array minus 1). So, if you have five items in an array called `arr`, the steps of the algorithm looks like this:

```
end_idx = arr.size - 1 # => 4
new_arr = []

new_arr[0] = { value: arr[end_idx - 0][:value], contents: arr[0][:contents] }
new_arr[1] = { value: arr[end_idx - 1][:value], contents: arr[1][:contents] }
new_arr[2] = { value: arr[end_idx - 2][:value], contents: arr[2][:contents] }
new_arr[3] = { value: arr[end_idx - 3][:value], contents: arr[3][:contents] }
new_arr[4] = { value: arr[end_idx - 4][:value], contents: arr[4][:contents] }
```

As you can see, every step is the same but with one number incremented, so I bet you already know how to turn this into a loop:

```
end_idx = arr.size - 1 # => 4
new_arr = []

0.upto(end_idx) do |idx|
  new_arr[idx] = { value: arr[end_idx - idx][:value],
                   contents: arr[idx][:contents] }
end
```

Easy, and to be honest a perfectly good solution. However, it's not very "Rubyish." How do we make it more Rubyish? I'm glad you asked!

#### Make it more Rubyish

It's a pretty common situation to want, as an output, an array with one item corresponding to each item in an input array. Because it's so common, we have the [`Enumerable#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) method, which does exactly that: It "maps" every item in an input array (or other Enumerable) to an item in an output array.

`map` walks over the items of the array, which is just what we need, but it's missing one thing we need: The index of the current item. To get that, we can "chain" the `with_index` method onto the `map` method, and now, in addition to the array item itself, the block will be passed a second argument, which is its index. Now we have everything we need:

```
end_idx = vals.size - 1

arr.map.with_index do |hsh, idx|
  { value: arr[end_idx - idx][:value],
    contents: hsh[:contents] }
end
```

Alternatively, if we don't want to explicitly specify the structure of the hash (as we might if the hash comes from, say, user input or a database query and might have keys other than `:value` and `:contents` that we want to preserve without having to keep track of changes to the input form or database schema), we could do this:

```
end_idx = vals.size - 1

arr.map.with_index do |hsh, idx|
  hsh.merge(value: arr[end_idx - idx][:value])
end
```

But I've saved the best for last.

#### At last...

```
arr.zip(arr.reverse_each).map do |a, b|
  a.merge(value: b[:value])
end
```

What's going on here? The [`Array#zip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-zip) method takes two arrays and "zips" them up, so e.g. `[1, 2, 3].zip([:a, :b, :c])` yields `[[1, :a], [2, :b], [3, :c]]`, so we do that with our array and its reverse (or, rather, an Enumerable that yields successive items from the end of the array, which is what `reverse_each` returns), and then we use `map` to set the value at `:value` from the latter on a copy of the former (using `merge`).

**Bonus:** Why `reverse_each` and not just `reverse`? Because we can make it *lazy*! Suppose `arr` has a billion items. If you call `arr.zip(arr.reverse)`, now you have a (two-dimensional) array with two billion items. Maybe that's not a big deal (or maybe you don't have anywhere near a billion items), but if it is, laziness can help us out:

```
new_enum = arr.lazy.zip(arr.reverse_each).map do |a, b|
  a.merge(value: b[:value])
end
# => #<Enumerator::Lazy: ...>
```

All we've done is added `lazy`, and now we get an Enumerator back instead of an array. This won't even do any work until we call, say, `each` or some other Enumerable method on it, and when we do that it will only operate on as many items as we ask it to. For example, say we just want the first three items:

```
new_enum.take(3).to_a
# => [ { value: 1000000000, contents: "one" },
#      { value:  999999999, contents: "two" },
#      { value:  999999998, contents: "three" } ]
```

Thanks to laziness, we never had to make a copy of the whole array and reverse it (and take up the corresponding amount of memory); we only had to deal with three items.

And if you do want all of the items, but still want to avoid making a copy of the whole array, just call `new_enum.to_a`.